# Double wire Hot/Neutral are both copper and identical - how to identify them?

Tags: wiring

I’m adding an on/off switch to an antique table lamp & I can’t identify the hot/neutral wires. The double wire is copper on both sides & the coverings are identical, no ribbing, no writing, no distinctions whatsoever. How to safely proceed?

Comment: Unless your meter will sense polarity it will difficult to determine. However, as said below it doesn’t really matter for bulbs.

Comment: It does matter for screw-in bulbs where the screw-in collar should be neutral because making it hot makes it a little more dangerous to change bulbs.  For table lamps you can say the lamp should be unplugged before changing a bulb, but wiring it correctly adds another margin of safety.   For any other kind of socket (other than screw-in) it really doesn't matter.  Two indistinguishable pins on the bottom of a bulb can be connected either way to hot and neutral.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the lamp is diconnected.
Unscrew the bulb, and use continuity meter between the bottom of bulb socket and the plug. The wire connected to the bottom pin is traditionally "hot" while the threaded part holding the bulb should be "neutral".

Caveat: Since the plug itself can be plugged either way in, it doesn't matter which wire is actually hot, so the switch can be on either one. Light bulbs don't care.

Comment: For the last 30 years (at least), in the US, plugs & receptacles have been polarized, meaning one blade is larger than the other. That means that you _cannot_ plug it in either way. This applies to lights, toasters, and _every_ other corded electrical item (legally) for sale in the US. Other than that, great answer.

Comment: Sadly, not all countries have polarized plugs (looking at you, Euro/shucko). The wall sockets may also have the wires swapped, so for safety, always assume both the wires may be live.

Comment: This answer has a couple of problems as it currently stands.  1) It only applies to screw-in sockets.  For most other types there is no distinction between hot and neutral.  2) The caveat should not say that "it doesn't matter".  It should say that plugs may not be polarized and sockets may be wired incorrectly therefore users should not rely on correct wiring to wantonly touch the screw collar.  But that doesn't mean you should not attempt to wire it correctly.    Thank you for joining and contributing!  You can improve your answer with the Edit button.

Comment: If you don't have a continuity meter you can buy one for $15 or make one with a flashlight and a little aluminum foil and paper.

Comment: @FreeMan The size of the blades on an old unpolarized US plug are the size of the smaller blade of a polarized plug, and thus can indeed be plugged in either way, even in a modern polarized socket. I think one could assume the  _antique_ lamp has such a plug, because if it had a polarized plug, LLLDNY could have likely told the hot/neutral wires from the plug itself.

Comment: If using a single-pole switch then an unpolarised plug should be swapped for a polarized plug (with a wider neutral blade) so the switch is always operating on the hot wire (which should, as already noted, be connected to the center contact on a screw-in bulb holder). Alternatively, or as well, @LLLDNY can use a double-pole switch which switches both hot and neutral conductors.

Comment: If the OP is adding a switch, then adding a polarized plug will not be difficult, once the right wire is found.

Comment: The bottom pin being hot isn't *traditional* - it's because it's vastly safer that way.  The light bulb doesn't care which is hot, but if you're switching the neutral then the socket is still live when you're changing the bulb - as is the "neutral" shell while the bulb is in there, and the **humans** *will* care whether the lamp will murder them while they're changing a bulb or not.

Comment: @jay613
1. Since this is antique lamp, it most likely uses Edison 27 screw-in. 
2. There is no country tag (unless everything untagged is assumed USA??). Piggybacking on other comment - polarized plugs only became thing in US recently.
If Its not hardwired into house, assume it can be plugged either way and almost certainly will be plugged wrong way. *Never* touch the screw collar when replacing light bulbs.
In my answer I provided both "what should be" (hot at bottom of socket) and "what is" (will work either way).

Answer (score 1):

If this is USA-style wiring and the plug is polarized then the wide blade is neutral. On a 9-volt battery the larger connector is the negative terminal. It turns out that the battery's terminal spacing is about the same as the spacing of the blades on the plug..

Get an assistant to hold the battery to the plug so that the large negative terminal is touching the wide blade of the plug. Use a volt meter to look for the 9 volts in the wiring of the lamp. If you measure -9 volts then reverse the red and black meter leads. When you measure +9 volts, the red lead is on the "hot" conductor and the black lead is on the "neutral" conductor.

Comment: A volt meter with a battery is a continuity meter, which almost every volt meter includes.  So the extra battery in this answer is not normally necessary.

Comment: @jay613 Yes, that's true. I like teaching the external battery approach because the concept can be easily extended to work on a pair of conductors of arbitrary length, even when the ends of the pair are immovable and much further apart than the length of a meter's test leads (wiring in a building or vehicle, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

step one: look at the plug. Are the blades the same size? If not the wide one is the neutral, and you should from that point be able to trace the relevant wire by pinch. If in the more common case in old lamps the blades are the same size proceed to step two.

step two: make a hard decision: modern safety or period accurate. If you are going period accurate, just pick a wire and switch it. I would contrary to general best practices switch the wire going to the outer screw of the socket as it makes it slightly safer when changing bulbs at the higher risk of shocks due to broken sockets. If on the other hand you want modern safety you need to either replace the plug with a polarized plug or replace the cord at which point  you can proceed to step one.